# Should I commit poetry.lock or pyproject.toml, or both?

Tags: package, python-poetry

I'm coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037557/should-i-commit-lock-file-changes-separately-what-should-i-write-for-the-commi) from 2020 and I'm completely lost. What I could gather is that the official `poetry` docs' advise is to commit `poetry.lock` to the repo, but there are many developers warning not to do this and only commit `pyproject.toml` instead.

I just want to build a Python package that is installable via `pip install xxx`. Is there any consensus as to what the correct approach is today? Should I commit only one of those files or both of them?

Comment: AFAICT for applications commit both, for libraries commit `pyproject.toml` (and optionally `poetry.lock`).
 When users install using pip install, the version constraints in `pyproject.toml` would be used and not `poetry.lock`

Comment: That's in FAQ: https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#committing-your-poetrylock-file-to-version-control

Answer (score 0):

When committing your Python project to a repository, consider these approaches based on your project type:

**Libraries**

Commit pyproject.toml to allow flexible dependency resolution for users. This ensures that your library can be easily integrated with other projects without causing dependency conflicts.

**Applications**

Commit both pyproject.toml and poetry.lock to ensure a consistent environment across all development and deployment stages. This locks down the exact versions of dependencies used, reducing the risk of discrepancies between environments.

**Optional: requirements.txt generation with poetry**

If you need to support environments that use requirements.txt, you can use Poetry to generate this file. While you typically wouldn't commit requirements.txt for a Poetry-managed project, you might do so for compatibility with deployment systems that require it. In this case, commit the generated requirements.txt alongside your pyproject.toml for applications, but for libraries, you might want to avoid committing it to keep dependency resolution flexible.